# Differentiation of non-separable function

Tags: linear-algebra

I have computationally-intensive simulation tool that returns a result Y where Y = fun(N,T) and N = fun(x) and T = fun(x).

I would like to return gradients dY/dx and it's expensive to use finite difference.

I can get dN/dx, dT/dx, dY/dN and dY/dT cheaply, so I kind of hoped that:

dY/dx = dY/dN * dN/dx + dY/dT * dT/dx would be a passable approximation.

But this doesn't give very good results if I compare to finite difference values.

A colleague thought that it may be because Y = fun(N,T) is not separable which he described as meaning Y ~= fun(N) * fun(T).

As you've probably gathered I'm not much of a mathematician.  Can anyone give me some tips on how I might compute dY/dx correctly or at least get a better approximation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is

$$\frac{dY}{dx}=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial N}\frac{dN}{dx}+\frac{\partial Y}{\partial T}\frac{dT}{dx},$$

and this is exact. Separability is not required.

But your notation $\dfrac{dY}{dN}$ and $\dfrac{dY}{dT}$ is suspect.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help Yves.  So it should work and I need to investigate further why my implementation in code doesn't agree with finite difference directly on dY/dx.

Comment: @Justin: what do you mean by $\dfrac{dY}{dN}$ ?

Comment: I didn't appreciate the difference between a d and a curly d but a colleague has explained it.  it should be curly d as per your correction.

Comment: @Justin: in the frame of multivariate problems, you need to be cautious about this.